# How to disable auto completion in ui.ace editor in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ace-editor

I am using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace directive to implement ace editor in my angular JS application.

Everything works well, i just want to know, how to disable the auto completion in the editor. I am using it in mode:html, and whenever I type in any opening tag like div, closing tag is added automatically. I want to disable this behaviour

Comment: you need to set enableBehaviors option to false on ace editor instance, I am not sure how to do that from angualar wrapper

Comment: I did find a way to access the ace editor instance, its mentioned in here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace#ace-instance-direct-access , so will try your suggestion. Thanks for the lead.